# GParted: unable to shrink the extended partiion

Tags: linux, partitioning, gparted

This is my exact situation

[image]

I ended in this situation because my goal is to grow /dev/sda1.

Actually, seems that gparted cannot shrink my extended partition.

It is complaining about a Gparted bug related to shrinking after the end of a volume.. Obviously I've no idea of what is saying.

Is there a way to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up choosing to aling the extended partition to 'cylinder' instead of 'MB'.

It worked.

**EDIT**

This short answer received some useful comments I want to incorporate here:

> This may have significant negative impact on performance on SSDs and flash-based media. – gronostaj
>
> Leave 1MB free between partitions and you can use alignment by MB instead of by Cylinder -  K7AAY
>
> You may also have several old kernels in sda1 which you don't need any more. – K7AAY

Comment: This may have significant negative impact on performance on SSDs and flash-based media.

Comment: Leave 1MB free between partitions and you can use alignment by MB instead of by Cylinder. Also, it's far better to use `sudo parted -l` in a terminal and to copy the result, then paste the result into a question, than use use a screenshot of gparted.

Comment: You may also have several old kernels in sda1 which you don't need any more.

Comment: @gronostaj and @K7AAY: thanks for all usefull suggestions, I'll try to correct alygnment and eventually post an update. In my case it's a virtualized disk on vmware, but underlying disk is an SSD. About the command `sudo parted -l` I didn't know. I'll post this command's result next question.